How to write data to the control registers of the accelerometer LIS3LV02DQ?
UPD: added an oscilloscope view
I am writing a driver to measure acceleration using the accelerometer LIS3LV02DQ. I use STM32F411 and CMSIS. I connected a four-channel SPI and set it to a frequency of about 1 MHz. I am able to read the register values from the accelerometer, but nothing happens when writing the values in them. Using an oscilloscope, I can see that the output signals from the STM32 look exactly like in datasheet, but the accelerometer does not respond to them. Also, SPI2->SR on STM32 does not show that some error occurred during transmission over SPI. What could be the mistake?
The source code of my functions:
void setup_LIS_spi() {
    // set GPIO pins
    // set PB10 as input, PB12 (CS) as output, PB15:13 as AF
    GPIOB->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODER12_0 | GPIO_MODER_MODER13_1 
                        | GPIO_MODER_MODER14_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER15_1);   
    GPIOB->OSPEEDR |= ((0xFF << 24) | (3 << 20)); // high speed for PB15:PB12 & PB10 pins
        // enable AF05 for PB13 (SCK), PB14 (MISO) and PB15 (MOSI)
    GPIOB->AFR[1] |= ((5 << 20) | (5 << 24) | (5 << 28)); 

    // set SPI2 properties
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;  // master mode
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;   // software slave management
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;   // internal slave select
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;   // SPI enable
    
    // transmission of 16 bits
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_DFF;

    // APB2 = 50 MHz
    // Baud rate ~ 1 MHz = (50 / 16) MHz
    SPI2->CR1 |= (3 << 3);

    // LIS3LV02DQ
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CPOL;
    SPI2->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CPHA;
}

static inline void transfer_spi2_16bit(const uint16_t byte_send, uint16_t *byte_read) {
    while (SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_BSY);  // wait for when spi is not busy
    SPI2->DR = byte_send;
    while(!(SPI2->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)); // wait for when rx buffer is not empty
    *byte_read = SPI2->DR & 0xFFFF;
}

// dalay = 10 000 == 1 ms
inline void __attribute__((always_inline)) delay(uint32_t delay) {
   while(delay--) __asm("");
}

void LIS3_write_data(uint8_t address, uint8_t data) {
    // the first 8 bits indicate the address of the register to be communicated with
    // the next 8 bits transmit the value to be written to this register
    // The 16th bit must be equal to 0 in order for a register entry to occur.
    uint16_t tx_data = ((address << 8) | data) & 0x7fff;
    uint16_t trash = 0;
    
    CS_OFF;
    transfer_spi2_16bit(tx_data, &trash);
    // the delay is manually adjusted so that CS becomes 1 when all bits are sent
    delay(105);
    CS_ON;
}

uint8_t LIS3_read_data(uint8_t address) {
    address |= READ_FLAG;
    uint16_t rx_data = 0;
    uint16_t tx_data = (address << 8);

    CS_OFF;
    transfer_spi2_16bit(tx_data, &rx_data);
    delay(105);
    CS_ON;

    // the required data is in the lower 8 bits
    return (uint8_t)(rx_data & 0x00FF);
}


If I just read the WHO_AM_I register, then its correct value is returned to me:
int main() {
    setup_LIS_spi();
    while (1) {
         // value after reset
         LIS3_read_data(0x0F); // return 0x3A
         LIS3_read_data(0x20); // return 0x07
    }
}

if I write a value to a register as initialization, and then read the value of the same register, then I return the unchanged value:
int main() {
    setup_LIS_spi();
    LIS3_write_data(0x20, 0x87)
    while (1) {
         LIS3_read_data(0x20); // return 0x07
    }
}

if I call the register write function in an infinite loop, then 0xff is returned to me when reading
int main() {
    setup_LIS_spi();
    while (1) {
         LIS3_write_data(0x20, 0x87)
         delay(10000);
         LIS3_read_data(0x20); // return 0xFF
    }
}

These are the transmission waveforms, MISO and MOSI occur simultaneously in 16 SCL cycles. Different photos because I didn't have enough hands
This is what MOSI looks like when I writing:

and this is what MISO looks like when I writing:

This is what I send on MOSI when I read:

this is what I see when reading from the accelerometer on MISO:

this is what MISO looks like if I first send 8 bits of data, not addresses:

and that's what I get by MISO in this case:


Show your oscilloscope view for LIS3_write_data() function? Does the data transmitted with the correct sequence? that is address byte first, followed by data?

Yes, I can see the correct packet on the oscilloscope. The first 8 bits are the address, and the next 8 bits contain the data I need.

I'm pretty I found the main problem in the LIS3_write_data() function, but I don't know for sure. I'd better be able to help if you post the oscilloscope traces.

I think the data is being sent in the opposite byte order that you want in LIS3_write_data()
If the ST SPI peripheral is configured with 8 bit frames, then it sends data out in LSB chunks from the DR.
The version of LIS3_write_data() that you posted puts the 'address' byte in the MSB of the SPI2_DR register like this:
    uint16_t tx_data = ((address << 8) | data) & 0x7fff;

I think you should try changing it to this instead:
    uint16_t tx_data = (data << 8) | (address & 0x7f);

Here's some justification from the manual. I'm reading this out of the manual for a different ST micro, but I think the SPI peripheral would work the same. I realize its a wordy justification, but check your chip's manual in case there's a diagram that's more helpful than the text.

When the data frame size fits into one byte (less than or equal to 8 bits), data packing is
used automatically when any read or write 16-bit access is performed on the SPIx_DR
register. ... At first, the SPI
operates using the pattern stored in the LSB of the accessed word, then with the other half
stored in the MSB.


No, it doesn't work that way. I also added a package view on the oscilloscope
